# Survival Shooter unity enemies wont take damage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing the survival shooter tutorial for unity and I just added the script which makes the enemies take damage from the players gun. I added the script to the enemy but whenever I play it they dont take damage

I dont get any errors or warnings in the console and they can still attack me and move fine, but they never take damage and the bullets pass right through them

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyDamage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int startingHealth = 100;           // The amount of health the enemy starts the game with.
    public int currentHealth;                  // The current health the enemy has.
    public float sinkSpeed = 2.5f;             // The speed at which the enemy sinks through the floor when dead.
    public int scoreValue = 10;                // The amount added to the player's score when the enemy dies.
    public AudioClip deathClip;                // The sound to play when the enemy dies.


    Animator anim;                             // Reference to the animator.
    AudioSource enemyAudio;                    // Reference to the audio source.
    ParticleSystem hitParticles;               // Reference to the particle system that plays when the enemy is damaged.
    CapsuleCollider capsuleCollider;           // Reference to the capsule collider.
    bool isDead;                               // Whether the enemy is dead.
    bool isSinking;                            // Whether the enemy has started sinking through the floor.


    void Awake()
    {
        // Setting up the references.
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        enemyAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        hitParticles = GetComponentInChildren<ParticleSystem>();
        capsuleCollider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();

        // Setting the current health when the enemy first spawns.
        currentHealth = startingHealth;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // If the enemy should be sinking...
        if (isSinking)
        {
            // ... move the enemy down by the sinkSpeed per second.
            transform.Translate(-Vector3.up * sinkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }


    public void TakeDamage(int amount, Vector3 hitPoint)
    {
        // If the enemy is dead...
        if (isDead)
        // ... no need to take damage so exit the function.
        return;

        // Play the hurt sound effect.
        enemyAudio.Play();
        Debug.Log("damage");

        // Reduce the current health by the amount of damage sustained.
        currentHealth -= amount;

        // Set the position of the particle system to where the hit was sustained.
        hitParticles.transform.position = hitPoint;

        // And play the particles.
        hitParticles.Play();

        // If the current health is less than or equal to zero...
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            // ... the enemy is dead.
            Death();
        }
    }


    void Death()
    {
        // The enemy is dead.
        isDead = true;

        // Turn the collider into a trigger so shots can pass through it.
        capsuleCollider.isTrigger = true;

        // Tell the animator that the enemy is dead.
        anim.SetTrigger("Dead");

        // Change the audio clip of the audio source to the death clip and play it (this will stop the hurt clip playing).
        enemyAudio.clip = deathClip;
        enemyAudio.Play();
    }


    public void StartSinking()
    {
        // Find and disable the Nav Mesh Agent.
        GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().enabled = false;

        // Find the rigidbody component and make it kinematic (since we use Translate to sink the enemy).
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;

        // The enemy should no sink.
        isSinking = true;

        // Increase the score by the enemy's score value.
        ScoreManager.score += scoreValue;

        // After 2 seconds destory the enemy.
        Destroy(gameObject, 2f);
    }
}
```

Comment: ...that's because the enemies are very very good at surviving... My apologies, simply ignore me... ;-)

Comment: By the way, you make it really inconvenient for someone wanting to inline your code into your question. Requiring to create/register an account with that web site just to be able to get the plain text version of the paste/code is just asinine...

Comment: Unity's tutorials are very complete, you probably missed a step, go through it again and make sure you didn’t miss anything.

Comment: From where do you call TakeDamage?

Comment: are you missing say a `Rigid Body` on the character?

Comment: @johnny5 there is one and it still wont work

Comment: Is there a rigid body on the bullet as well?

Comment: Also is it possible your bullet is passing through your character and they're not colliding during the frame?

Comment: @johnny5 they are passing through the enemy, it isnt an actual bullet model it just uses a line renderer

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a layer, or a tag to either your `enemies`, `bullets`, or `both`. Check also the layer collision matrix in `project settings -> physic`

Comment: this shouldn't be categorized as an answer. The comments under the OP are a much better place for suggestions.

Comment: @Daniel the real issue is that this isn't a valid question

Comment: @Jichael everything is checked